# Partial derivative of summation over function

Tags: derivatives, summation, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

Hi I'm trying to understand an algorithm that involves maximizing a function over a probability distribution i.e. $\pi(a)$ of a random variable $a$.

I don't understand why the first term of the partial derivative of the lagrangian w.r.t. $\pi(a)$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\pi(a)} \sum_a\pi(a)r(a)$$

equals to
$$r(a)$$

where $\pi(a)$ is a probability distribution and $a\in A$ which is a finite set of actions that the agent can take.

Both the summation and the $\pi(a)$ function get eliminated in the above equation. Why is that?

---

We want to find:
$$\max_{\pi(a)} E \left[ r(a)\right] + \beta \mathcal{H}(\pi(a)) $$
i.e.
$$\max_{\pi(a)} \sum_{a} \pi(a) r(a) - \beta \sum_{a} \pi(a) \ln \pi(a) $$

$$\max_{\pi(a)} \min_{\lambda} \mathcal{L}(\pi(a),\lambda)=\sum_{a} \pi(a) r(a) - \beta \sum_{a} \pi(a) \ln \pi(a) + \lambda \bigl( \sum_{a}\pi(a)-1 \bigr)$$

Taking the Lagrangian.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \pi(a)}\mathcal{L}(\pi(a),\lambda)=0 \text{ , }\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}\mathcal{L}(\pi(a),\lambda)=0$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \pi(a)} \sum_{a}\pi(a)r(a) - \beta \sum_{a}\pi(a) \ln \pi(a) + \lambda \bigl( \sum_{a}\pi(a)-1 \bigr) =0 $$
$\sum_{a}\pi(a)=1 $ as we are summing over all probabilities

$$r(a) - \beta \ln \pi(a) - \beta +\lambda =0 $$

$$\beta \ln \pi(a) = r(a) - \beta +\lambda$$
$$\pi(a) = exp \bigl [ \frac{1}{\beta}(r(a) - \beta +\lambda) \bigr ]$$
$$\pi(a) = \frac{1}{Z}exp \bigl [ \frac{r(a)}{\beta} \bigr ] \text{ where } Z = \sum_{a} exp \bigl [ \frac{r(a)}{\beta} \bigr ]$$

For reference, the original formulas are:

[formulars][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SLJw.png

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please avoid posting images and references as links. Use MathJax for formatting! And don't forget to add context - source, motivation, attempt!

Comment: Hint: what is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}( x_1 r_1+x_2 r_2)$

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks for the hint, but I think it's a bit different here. In your case, the partial derivative is clearly $r_1$. However in the formula, the summation is over a random variable a - not the subscription in your example. So in a way the formula is more like $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sum_xxf(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x_1f(x_1)+x_2f(x_2)+...) $ and it somehow equals to f(x).

Comment: Can you give a link to the original algorithm, please?

Comment: @Jamie Yes, but it is a finite sum so you should exploit that.

Comment: @AlDante The original algorithm is to maximize the expected reward with max entropy for a Markov decision process. It's from a lecture video online (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_9YQBN45fo&list=PLwRJQ4m4UJjNBPJdt8WamRAt4XKc639wF&index=2) And I just realised you edited my post. It's much better now. Thank you!

Comment: @ancientmathematician The problem is that each $x_1$,$x_2$... is actually a fixed value in the domain of x. (that corresponds to the domain of actions in the original formula). So shouldn't $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x_1f(x_1) + x_2f(x_2)+...)$ be 0? (because each term $x_if(x_i)$ is just a constant when $x_i$ is a fixed value

Comment: @Jamie: Thank you, and you're welcome. I asked because I wondered if you were looking at a reinforcement learning paper - but I am also interested in Markov decision processes, especially as they pertain to robotics, so that's cool.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I think the reason you can drop the sums is because you are actually differentiating w.r.t. one specific value of a, namely the action that maximizes the entropy. In this case all other elements of the sum drop out of the derivative. 

Is this correct? (PS: I am not the OP, if that makes any difference).